# Mock python decorator in unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, decorator

I am trying to test a function that is decorated. Is there a way to mock a decorator and test function in isolation, when decorator is already applied?

```
import mock


def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return 1
    return wrapper


def mocked(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return 2
    return wrapper


@decorator
def f():
    return 0


with mock.patch('test.decorator') as d:
    d.side_effect = mocked
    assert f() == 2  # error
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're going for here... Are you trying to change the function that decorated `f` for this test?

Comment: Yes I am trying to replace decorator with mocked.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a simple solution.

This is a similar question: [How to strip decorators from a function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166118/how-to-strip-decorators-from-a-function-in-python)

You can either modify the original code just for testing, or use something like this library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/undecorated in order to write a helper function to switch from the original wrapper to the testing wrapper:

```
from undecorated import undecorated
mocked(undecorated(f))()
```