# Python 3.6 inspect.signature() doesn't show arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, inspect, method-signature

I have a function:

```
def report(start=1, quantity=100, days_left=7, min_app_version=None):
```

I want to get argument names and default values, something like

```
{'start':1, 'quantity':100, 'days_left':7, 'min_app_version':None}
```

(or at least two lists) from outside this function

when I do

```
import inspect
print(inspect.signature(report))
```

I get

(*args, **kwargs)

Why doesn't 'inspect.signature' see function arguments?

SOLVED: THE PROBLEM WAS BECAUSE OF A DECORATOR

Comment: Seems to [work fine](https://ideone.com/NuYSRH) for me.

Comment: I have Python 3.6 installed and works ok: the signature printed is `(start=1, quantity=100, days_left=7, min_app_version=None)`

Comment: Does `report` have any annotations or modified dynamically in any way? What does `inspect.getfullargspec(report)` show?

Comment: @FHTMitchell it shows:
FullArgSpec(args=[], varargs='args', varkw='kwargs', defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})

Comment: Great, glad you found a solution. You should post an answer to your own question (and show the code with the decorator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even better than removing the decorator, you can tell the decorator to make the function wrapper look like the wrapped function to inspection tools using [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)

Instead of

```
def decorator(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Wrapped")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@decorator
def report(start=1, quantity=100, days_left=7, min_app_version=None):
    pass

print(inspect.signature(report))
# (*args, **kwargs)
```

You can do

```
from functools import wraps

def decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Wrapped")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@decorator
def report(start=1, quantity=100, days_left=7, min_app_version=None):
    pass

print(inspect.signature(report))
# (start=1, quantity=100, days_left=7, min_app_version=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone ever get stuck with this error, just delete the function decorator.

```
@time_count
def report(start=1, quantity=100, days_left=7, min_app_version=None):
```

You can also help yourself with:
[How to strip decorators from a function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166118/how-to-strip-decorators-from-a-function-in-python)