# how to avoid decorators while unit testing in python flask application

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, pytest, python-decorators

I am new to python and flask. I wanted to create unit tests for an api written. We have used `jwt` for authentication.

To unit test, I don't want the flow to enter `@jwt_required` decorator. In addition to that I have chained a few other decorators for that method.

```
class A():

   @jwt_required()
   @mandatory_fields_check
   @unlock_and_lock()
   def get(self, address, name): 
      ..
      ..
      ..
       return jsonify(
            {"payload": data,
             "message": "data received successfully"}), 200
```

Unit test I am trying to write

```
def test_get():
   a_obj = A()
   a_obj.get("address123", 'xyz')
```

When I run above test using py.test, I am getting Runtime error

```
    def _find_app():
            top = _app_ctx_stack.top
            if top is None:
               raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
     RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
E
E           This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
E           to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
E           this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
E           documentation for more information.
```

Below are my objectives:

1. I don't want flow to enter decorators logic
2. Jwt decorator is asking for context. However my intention is to unit test this method as a normal class method without any flask features.
3. How can I mock objects created inside the method under test?

Comment: Why not test the method by calling it directly in the test? i.e Create an object for that class and call the method with the relevant parameters

Comment: I tried that and as I mentioned the flow is going to jwt decorator

Answer (score 2):

**Instead of trying to mock the decorator, mock out the function the decorator is calling.**

I ran into a similar obstacle using flask_jwt_extended where I wanted to mock out the `jwt_required` decorator.

```
@jwt_required
def post(payload)
    ....
```

Instead of

```
mock.patch('flask_jwt_extended.jwt_required')
```

I looked at the function the `jwt_required` decorator was calling (which in this case was `verify_jwt_in_request` from `flask_jwt_extended.view_decorators`). So,

```
mock.patch('flask_jwt_extended.view_decorators.verify_jwt_in_request')
```

did the trick!

Comment: Hi, I tried your way but it is still not working for me. I am sure I am missing something but not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

[based on the description here](http://httphttps://github.com/mattupstate/flask-jwt/issues/53)

It should be like this, but not tested.

```
import mock
def mock_jwt_required(realm):
    return

@mock.patch('flask_jwt.jwt_required', side_effect=mock_jwt_required)
def test_get(jwt_required_fn):
    a_obj = A()
    a_obj.get("address123", 'xyz')
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this library called undecorated and its working fine for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35418639

https://pypi.org/project/undecorated/

This is clean, however if there is a any easier way without importing libraries please suggest.