# How to call self method and get data in flask?

Tags: python, api, flask

I want to call app.route method from another app.route method. As an example the code look like this simply. I want to call getMethod() function inside the postMethod() function. How can I do this?

```
@app.route('/ex1')
def getMethod():
    return "some value"

@app.route('/ex2', methods=['POST'])
def postMethod():
    # want to call getMethod() and get the return value
    # save data to database
    return jsonify('created'), 201
```

Comment: run it as normal function `getMethod()`. Or code which you need in both functions put in separated function and run this function in `getMethod()` and `postMethod()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166118/how-to-strip-decorators-from-a-function-in-python)

A possible solution will be to create a normal function without the decorator, then call it at the different places where you want to.

```
@app.route('/ex1')
def getMethod():
    return commonMethod()

def commonMethod():
    return "some value"

@app.route('/ex2', methods=['POST'])
def postMethod():
    result = commonMethod()
    return jsonify('created'), 201
```