# Correct Way to Specify User-Defined Function in PySpark Pandas UDF

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am using pyspark 2.4.2, so the per the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.2/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html) for this version one can do this to create a GROUPED_MAP:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)],("id", "v"))

@pandas_udf(returnType="id long, v double", functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def subtract_mean(pdf):
    v = pdf.v
    return pdf.assign(v=v - v.mean())

df.groupby("id").apply(subtract_mean).show()
```

This works but you cannot call `subtract_mean` as a normal python function that is passed a pandas DataFrame. But if you do this, it will work:

```
def subtract_mean(pdf):
    v = pdf.v
    return pdf.assign(v=v - v.mean())

sub_spark = pandas_udf(f=subtract_mean, returnType="id long, v double", functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)

df.groupby("id").apply(sub_spark).show()
```

Now you can call `subtract_mean` from python passing a pandas DataFrame. How does one do this using the annotation approach? It is not clear from the docs how to do this. What function is annotated and what function is given for the `f` parameter?

Comment: the two ways are equivalent for specifying an UDF. The decorator approach is just a neater way of doing things. The function that follows the decorator is passed as the `f` parameter. If you decorated a function, I don't think you can access the original, undecorated function.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Humpf

Comment: There is also a way to get back the original function, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024739/14165730 . perhaps `subtract_mean.__wrapped__` will give you back the original undecorated function.

Comment: Yes! That totally works: `pandas_dataframe.groupby("id").apply(subtract_mean.__wrapped__)`

Comment: I would suggest using the second approach in your question though. Using `__wrapped__` makes the code less readable.

Comment: Yes, I agree but I only need this for ease of unit testing the pandas udfs without spark. Thanks again.

Comment: Feel free to formalize this in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two ways are equivalent for specifying an UDF. The decorator approach is just a neater way of doing things. The function that follows the decorator is passed as the `f` parameter.

As described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024739/14165730), you can use `subtract_mean.__wrapped__` to get back the original undecorated function. The second approach in your question is more readble though. Using `__wrapped__` makes the code less readable. But if it's just for unit testing purposes, it should be fine.