# How to run the original function after decorating it as a click command?

Tags: python, python-click

I decorate my functions wit `@click.command` and `@click.option` to give command line access to the function.

But how can I then run the original function?

```py
import click


@click.command("user-info")
@click.option("--name")
def print_user_info(name: str):
    print(f"info for {name}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_user_info(name="john")
```

gives a type error:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

EDIT:
A workaround would be to add another function inside of the wrapped function:

```py
def print_user_info(name: str):
    print(f"info for {name}")


@click.command("user-info")
@click.option("--name")
def print_user_info_click(name: str):
    print_user_info(name=name)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166118/how-to-strip-decorators-from-a-function-in-python)
Someone mentioned a `__wrapped__` attribute.

Comment: the `__wrapped__` attribute might be part of functools or some other package, but a function decorated with `click.command` and `click.option` does not have a `__wrapped__` attribute. Trying to access it raises an `AttributeError`:
`AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute '__wrapped__'`