# How to write testcases for Plotly Dash callback function?

Tags: python, pytest, plotly-dash

I am trying to write a testcase for a Dash callback function in a page which store selected rows of 2 datatables into `dash_core_components.Store`, and determine the state by `dash.callback_context`

Sample callback function in `index.py`

```
@app.callback(
    Output('rows-store', 'data'),
    Input('datatable1', 'selected_rows'),
    Input('datatable2', 'selected_rows'),
)
def store_row_selection(row1: list, row2: list) -> dict:
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    if not ctx.triggered:
        return {'row-index-v1': [0], 'row-index-v2': [0]}
    else:
        return {'row-index-v1': row1, 'row-index-v2': row2}
```

Sample testcase in `test.py`

```
def test_store_row_selection_1(app_datatable):
    r1 = [0]
    r2 = [1]
    result = store_row_selection(r1, r2)

    assert type(result) is dict
```

However, Pytest throws an exception when running, what is the proper way to test a callback function and how can I get this to work?

```
  @wraps(func)
    def add_context(*args, **kwargs):
>       output_spec = kwargs.pop("outputs_list")
E       KeyError: 'outputs_list'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend you to test the function undecorated by `@app.callback`.

Dash uses [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) for creating callbacks ([source code](https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/358c5089c929b2e99996f9d4ee6ec634f65437fe/dash/dash.py#L1004)). This means we have access to the [`__wrapped__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024739/9098350) attribute on the `store_row_selection` function.

The `__wrapped__` attribute gives us the original underlying function, `store_row_selection` in this case:

```
def test_store_row_selection_1():
    r1 = [0]
    r2 = [1]
    result = store_row_selection.__wrapped__(r1, r2)

    assert type(result) is dict
```

---

Another approach would be to split your callback code up into parts:

```
def do_stuff(row1, row2):
    # Do things
    return {"row-index-v1": row1, "row-index-v2": row2}


@app.callback(
    Output("rows-store", "data"),
    Input("datatable1", "selected_rows"),
    Input("datatable2", "selected_rows"),
)
def store_row_selection(row1: list, row2: list) -> dict:
    return do_stuff(row1, row2)
```

and test the function which is not dependent on Dash callbacks (`do_stuff` in this example).

**Update based on edit and comment**

> May I know if it is possible to trigger ctx.triggered in pytest as well?

`dash.call_context` is only available inside a callback ([source](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks)), so the `__wrapped__` approach wouldn't work in that case. The other approach (splitting up the function) would work as you could pass `ctx` to `do_stuff` and simulate `callback_context` in your tests.

Comment: Thanks! May I know if it is possible to trigger ctx.triggered in pytest as well? (Please see the updates in my question)

Comment: @KitLaw I've updated my answer. I don't really know of a better way, but maybe you could mock  `dash.callback_context` https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html