# How to bypass pytest fixture decorator?

Tags: python, pytest, decorator, python-decorators, fixtures

```
@pytest_fixture
def some_fix():
    return some_data
```

I want to call this some_fix function directly. How do I bypass pytest fixture decorator?

Comment: it depend if said decorator offer access to the original function, where that decorator come from?

Comment: Remove the decorator? Create a new function without decorator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to strip decorators from a function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166118/how-to-strip-decorators-from-a-function-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying any trick that bypasses the decorator has the same value as decrementing a number after incrementing it. The cleanest solution would be to define two functions:

```
def plain_function():
    # call this function when you need to bypass decorator
    pass


 @pytest.fixture
 def simlar_fixture():
    return plain_function()
```