# Call overridden base class method without triggering the base class decorator

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator, python-decorators

I have a base class like

```
class BaseTest:
  @setup_test(param='foo')
  def test_something():
    do stuff
```

I now want to override the param to the decorator

```
class NewTest:
  @setup_test(param='different value')
  def test_something():
    super().test_something()
```

The trouble is when I call `super().test_something()` it will call `BaseTest.test_something` wrapped with `@setup_test(param='foo')` which does some bootstrapping that will overwrite what was done in `@setup_test(param='different value')`.

I need to directly call the undecorated `BaseTest.test_something`

Comment: By itself, decorating a function literally replaces it with another object in the enclosing namespace. After passing `test_something` to `setup_test` the former is replaced by _whatever_ the decorator returns. _Usually_ a decorator returns another function that is at least similar to the one passed into it. And _usually_ (though less common) the decorator uses some mechanism to attach a reference to the original function as an attribute of the object it returns. (This is what the [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) decorator does for example.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to strip decorators from a function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166118/how-to-strip-decorators-from-a-function-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with is to use the [`__wrapped__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) attribute on `BaseTest.test_something`

```
class NewTest:
  @setup_test(param='different value')
  def test_something():
    super().test_something.__wrapped__(self)
```

This bypasses `@setup_test(param='foo')`

Comment: This solution only works, if the decorator adds a corresponding `__wrapped__` attribute. You did not specify in your question that the decorators were using the `functools.update_wrapper` function. The `__wrapped__` attribute is not some built-in Python magic. It is just an attribute that that particular `functools` function attaches to the output.

Comment: this is true, although best practice these days is to use @wraps when writing a decorator. If you didn't do that then this solution would not work