How to prevent multiple nested calls of a python decorator
Hi All the following is my code:
from functools import wraps

def log_return(level='DEBUG', label='Returned'):
    """
    Decorator for logging the return of a function

    level (string): logging level to use (DEBUG (default) or INFO)
    label (string): what to label the return as, (default 'Returned')
    """
    
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            func_return = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if level == 'DEBUG':
                print(f'{func.__name__} returned: {func_return}')
            else:
                print(f'{label}: {func_return}')
            return func_return
        return wrapper
    return decorator




@log_return()
def printer(text):
    return text
@log_return()
def printA():
    return printer('A')


print(printA())


When I run this I get the following output
printer returned: A
printA returned: A
A

What can I do to make only the 'printA' line get logged when running this code?
I tried using function attributes but they apparently get created during decoration so didn't work for me,
Use case: I am trying to reduce the number of statements getting logged. the top of the call stack should be enough
I tried this
from functools import wraps

def log_return(level='DEBUG', label='Returned'):
    """
    Decorator for logging the return of a function

    level (string): logging level to use (DEBUG (default) or INFO)
    label (string): what to label the return as, (default 'Returned')
    """
    
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if hasattr(func, 'log_it') and func.log_it:
                func.log_it = False
            func_return = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if hasattr(func, 'log_it') and func.log_it:
                if level == 'DEBUG':
                    print(f'{func.__name__} returned: {func_return}')
                else:
                    print(f'{label}: {func_return}')
            return func_return
        return wrapper
    decorator.log_it = True
    return decorator

Edit:
Found a related answer => https://stackoverflow.com/a/49978332
came up with
def log_unwrapped_return(func):
def inner(*args, **kwargs):
return inspect.unwrap(func)(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

this works, but I want something automatic, where I don't have to keep calling unwraps, for the moment I will be using the above,
